# On Shoenfield's Mathematical Logic, Chapter 6 Q2

Tags: logic, computability

I need help with Chapter 6, Exercise 2 of Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic*:

> Let $H$ and $K$ be recursive functions, and let $F$ and $G$ be defined inductively by:
> $$
> F(a,\mathfrak{a}) = H(\bar{F}(a,\mathfrak{a}), \bar{G}(a,\mathfrak{a}), a, \mathfrak{a}) \\
> G(a,\mathfrak{a}) = K(\bar{F}(a + 1,\mathfrak{a}), \bar{G}(a,\mathfrak{a}), a, \mathfrak{a})
> $$
> Show that $F$ and $G$ are recurseive. [Hint: Let $L(a,\mathfrak{a}) := \langle{F(a,\mathfrak{a}),G(a,\mathfrak{a})}\rangle$, and use **R14** to show that $L$ is recursive.]

---

My main issue lies with showing that $L$ is recursive. Suppose that is done, we can then conclude that:
$$
F(a,\mathfrak{a}) = \beta(L(a,\mathfrak{a}),1) \\
G(a,\mathfrak{a}) = \beta(L(a,\mathfrak{a}),2)
$$
where $\beta$ is the Godel beta function, which is recursive, so both $F$ and $G$ are recursive. However, I tried various methods to show that $L$ is recursive, such as expanding the definition of $F$ and $G$ in $L$, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\renewcommand{\c}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
\renewcommand{\bb}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\renewcommand{\In}{\mathrm{In}}
$
This proof is motivated by @M477's answer, and serves to fill in the details. Let $F,G_1,\dots,G_k$ be functions. We say that $F$ is a **recursive function of $G_1,\dots,G_k$** if there exists a recursive function $H$ such that:\begin{align*}
        F(a,\mathfrak{a}) = H(G_1(a,\mathfrak{a}),\dots,G_k(a,\mathfrak{a}),a,\mathfrak{a})\end{align*}

Note that:

1. If $G_1,\dots,G_k$ are all recursive and $F$ is a recursive function of $G_1,\dots,G_k$, then $F$ is recursive by **R2**.
2. If $F$ is a recursive function of $G_1,\dots,G_k$ and each $G_i$ is a recursive function of $H_1,\dots,H_\ell$, then $F$ is a recursive function of $H_1,\dots,H_\ell$ by **R2**.
3. If $F$ is a recursive function of $\bar{F}$, then $F$ is recursive by **R14**.

---

Following the hint, given $a,\mathfrak{a}$, define $L(a,\mathfrak{a}) := \c{F(a,\mathfrak{a}),G(a,\mathfrak{a})}$. To show that $L$ is recursive, we proceed in a few steps. The proof will proceed in several steps.

**Step 1 - Show that $\bar{F}$,$\bar{G}$ are both recursive functions of $\bar{L}$.** For $\bar{F}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\bar{F}(a,\mathfrak{a}) &= \mu x\bb{lh(x) = a \wedge \forall i_{i < a}\bb{(x)_i = F(i,a)}} \\
&= \mu x\bb{lh(x) = a \wedge \forall i_{i < a}\bb{(x)_i = ((\bar{L}(a,\mathfrak{a}))_i)_0}} 
\end{align*}
and similarly for $\bar{G}$ as well.

**Step 2 - Show that $F$ is a recursive function of $\bar{L}$.** By definition, we see that $F$ is a recursive function of $\bar{F},\bar{G}$, and is hence a recursive function of $\bar{L}$ by (2) above.

**Step 3 - Show that $(a,\mathfrak{a}) \mapsto \bar{F}(a+1,\mathfrak{a})$ is a recursive function of $\bar{L}$.** Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\bar{F}(a+1,\mathfrak{a}) &= \c{F(0,a),\dots,F(a,\mathfrak{a})} \\
&= \mu x\bb{lh(x) = a + 1 \wedge \In(x,a) = \bar{F}(a,\bar{a}) \wedge (x)_a = F(a,\mathfrak{a})}
\end{align*}
Thus, $(a,\mathfrak{a}) \mapsto F(a+1,\mathfrak{a})$ is a recursive function of $F,\bar{F}$, and is thus a recursive function of $\bar{L}$ by (2).

**Step 4 - Show that $G$ is a recursive function of $\bar{L}$.** Similarly, by definition we see that $G$ is a recursive function of $(a,\mathfrak{a}) \mapsto \bar{F}(a+1,\mathfrak{a}),\bar{G}$, and is hence a recursive function of $\bar{L}$ by the previous steps and (2) above.

**Step 5 - Show that $L$ is recursive.** Finally, since $L(a,\mathfrak{a}) = \c{F(a,\mathfrak{a}),G(a,\mathfrak{a})}$ and both $F$ and $G$ are recursive functions of $\bar{L}$, we have that $L$ is a recursive function of $\bar{L}$, and is hence recursive.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution and it seems to be correct.

If you hope to apply the R14, then you will need to introduce $\overline{L}(a,\textbf{a})$ which is, by usual definition, $\langle \langle F(0,\textbf{a}),G(0,\textbf{a})\rangle,...,\langle F(a-1,\textbf{a}),G(a-1,\textbf{a})\rangle \rangle$. Then $F(0,\textbf{a}), ..., F(a-1, \textbf{a}), G(0,\textbf{a}), ..., G(a-1, \textbf{a})$ are all just recursive functions of $\overline{L}(a,\textbf{a})$ since $((\overline{L}(a,\textbf{a}))_{i})_{0}$ are just recursive functions of $\overline{L}(a,\textbf{a})$ for $0\leq i\leq a-1$.Then $\overline{F}(a,\textbf{a})$ and $\overline{G}(a,\textbf{a})$ are just recursive functions of $\overline{L}(a,\textbf{a})$. Now it is quite clear and you will easily get that $L(a,\textbf{a}) = G(\overline{L}(a,\textbf{a}),a, \textbf{a})$ and apply R14, you get that F,G are both recursive.

(This is the first time I answer a Q here. So if there is anything wrong or unclear, please let me know :)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, and thanks for your answer. What do you mean by a function being a recursive function *of* another function?

Comment: The function, say F, takes another function, say G, as its variable and F is recursive. This feels like what happens on page 110 on Shoenfield's book, but instead of taking variables of G as variables of F, we take G as a whole as a variable of F.

Comment: Well, what you just said is not a precise definition. Regardless, following what I think your idea of a function being recursive of another is, your answer is too vague for me to follow. For instance, I don't see how your claim that "$\bar{F}(a,\mathbf{a})$ and $\bar{G}(a,\mathbf{a})$ are just recursive functions of $\bar{L}(a,\mathbf{a})$" holds.